# Perform spread on nested data frame

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr, spread

I'd like to perform `spread` on a nested data frame but can't work it out. Here's a toy data frame for using `spread` on a normal data frame:

```
df <- data.frame( A = 1:4, B = 5:8)
df %>% spread(A,B)

  1 2 3 4
1 5 6 7 8
```

Here's a toy example for a nested data frame and what I've tried (but doesn't work):

```
df <- data.frame( dummy=c(1,1,2,2), A = 1:4, B = 5:8)
df %>% 
   nest(-dummy) %>% 
   mutate(data = map(data, ~spread(.x$A,.x$B)))

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
   Evaluation error: Invalid column specification.
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The first argument of `spread` is a data frame, not a column. So maybe `map(data, ~spread(.x, A, B))`?

Comment: `spread` uses non-standard evaluation, so you can't use `$` subsetting; you need to provide a `.data` parameter, either with lukeA's suggestion above, or implicitly without the `~`: `df %>% nest(-dummy) %>% mutate(data = map(data, spread, A, B))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame( dummy=c(1,1,2,2), A = 1:4, B = 5:8)
df %>% 
  nest(-dummy) %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, ~spread(.x, key = A, value = B)))
```

Comment: Thanks to you and `lukeA` , who provided the answer first in the comments. (I wish I could give you more points @lukeA). I tried `mutate(data=map(data,~spread(.x,.x$A,.x$B)))`, which didn't work. Still figuring out argument types...